# org.osmf.media.MediaPlayer Throw Error: The specified capability is not currently supported

Tags: actionscript-3, media-player, osmf, m4a

I have a back end sound.php which can return .m4a sound file from web server and I can make a web request with id to the sound.php to return specify .m4a file. i.e. sound.php?id=1234

I am now trying to use   org.osmf.media.MediaPlayer  and AudioElement  and URLResource

```
  var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  var ae:AudioElement = new AudioElement(new URLResource("http://xxx.com/sound.php?id=12"));
  mediaPlayer.media = ae;
  mediaPlayer.play();
```

and it throw error of The specified capability is not currently supported .I have tested the link via browser which is return a .m4a file sucessfully .

I dont understand if it is claiming the requesting method or the returned file , would somebody has any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [`MediaPlayer.autoPlay`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/media/MediaPlayer.html#autoPlay) to `true` or you should wait until the media is loaded, which is signaled through the [`mediaPlayerStateChange`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/media/MediaPlayer.html#event%3amediaPlayerStateChange) event, with state [READY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/media/MediaPlayerState.html#READY).

**[UPDATE]**

As stated in the [NetStream - Adobe ActionScript® 3 (AS3 ) API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) page and also in the [Supported codecs | Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/supported-codecs-flash-player.html) page:

> Flash Player 9 Update 3 plays files derived from the standard MPEG-4
>   container format that contain H.264 video and/or HE-AAC audio, such as
>   F4V, MP4, **M4A**, MOV, MP4V, 3GP, and 3G2. One thing to note is that
>   protected MP4 files, such as those downloaded from iTunes or digitally
>   encrypted by FairPlay, are not supported.

It seems you will have to try the `NetStream` approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried both

MediaPlayer.autoPlay and mediaPlayerStateChage event, with state READY but it still throw the same error. I am now wondering if the MediaPlayer doesnt support .m4a file..

I found that the event mediaPlayerStateChange come back only with playbackError.

Comment: It works if i use NetStream.However, it cannot play the audio file unless the whole file is downloaded. Not like the Sound , it supports only mp3 but it can progressively download and play the audio file without media streaming server.